# PHP: Converting integer to int - getting error

Tags: php, casting

I understood there wasn't much, if any different between int and integer in PHP. I must be wrong.

I'm passing a integer value to a function which has int only on this value. Like so:-

```
$new->setPersonId((int)$newPersonId); // Have tried casting with (int) and intval and both
```

The other side I have:-

```
    public function setPersonId(int $value) {
        // foobar
    }
```

Now, when I run - I get the message:-

**"PHP Catchable fatal error:  Argument 1 passed to setPersonId() must be an instance of int, integer given"**

I have tried casting in the call with (int) and intval().

Any ideas?

Comment: PHP does not support type-hinting for the standard data types (int, doubles), but does support type-hinting of objects.

Comment: Sure - I read that too - so what's the solution?

Comment: remove 'int' from public function setPersonId(int $value)

Comment: read this: http://ch2.php.net/language.oop5.typehinting

Comment: As I mentioned, I've read this.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Type hinting in PHP only works for objects and not scalars, so PHP is expecting you be passing an object of type "int".

You can use the following as a workaround

```
public function setPersonId($value) {
    if (!is_int($value)) {
        // Handle error
    }
}
```

Comment: Sure, I read this - but how can you then handle that? You can not convert? Are we saying the value needs to be int from the start or nothing.

Comment: If you want the value to be an int, but `is_int` returns false, you could cast it `$value = (int) $value;`. If you don't care if it's an int or not, just remove the `is_int` check.

Comment: This is pretty horrid, but admittedly seems the only way to go. PHP doesn't get it :/

Comment: In PHP 7, type hinting (now called type declaration) allows specifying scalar types too, see http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.type-declaration

Answer (score -2):

To explicitly convert a value to integer, use either the (int) or (integer) casts. However, in most cases the cast is not needed, since a value will be automatically converted if an operator, function or control structure requires an integer argument. A value can also be converted to integer with the intval() function.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php

Answer (score -3):

Make sure that `PersonID` property is defined as int not integer:

```
private int $personId;
```

instead of

```
private integer $personId;
```

Comment: You are not in PHP, aren't you?