# Argument 1 passed to must be an instance of int, integer given

Tags: php, mysql

I am just beginning to learn php, and following an example from http://www.mysqltutorial.org/php-calling-mysql-stored-procedures/.

But got error "Argument 1 passed to must be an instance of int, integer given..." when I tried to run:

```
   <?php

    require_once 'dbconfig.php';

    /**
     * Get customer level
     * @param int $customerNumber
     * @return string
     */
    function getCustomerLevel(int $customerNumber) {
        try {
            $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);

            // calling stored procedure command
            $sql = 'CALL GetCustomerLevel(:id,@level)';

            // prepare for execution of the stored procedure
            $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);

            // pass value to the command
            $stmt->bindParam(':id', $customerNumber, PDO::PARAM_INT);

            // execute the stored procedure
            $stmt->execute();

            $stmt->closeCursor();

            // execute the second query to get customer's level
            $row = $pdo->query("SELECT @level AS level")->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            if ($row) {
                return $row !== false ? $row['level'] : null;
            }
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            die("Error occurred:" . $e->getMessage());
        }
        return null;
    }

    $customerNo = 103;
    echo sprintf('Customer #%d is %s', $customerNo, getCustomerLevel($customerNo));
```

looks to me the definition of the IN parameter as int is already done. Could you give me some hint how to make this work?

Comment: Sounds like you're running a PHP version < 7, where scalar type declarations were not possible yet.

Comment: So just remove the `int` form here: `getCustomerLevel(int $customerNumber)`

Comment: Upgrade to PHP 7, if you can. If you're just learning, might as well learn on the most current version.

Comment: I would argue that unless you define it in code like the example (unlikely) or type cast it, it will be a string when passed anyway (gotten from `$_POST`, DB etc. so why force `int` here?

Answer (score 13):

Type hinting / declaration for scalar types (bool, int, float, string) is supported from PHP 7.0.0 only.

See [PHP manual / Function arguments](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php) as well as [this answer to similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14259327/php-converting-integer-to-int-getting-error)

Answer (score 1):

No need to typehint parameters in PHP. You can use typehinting in some cases though (it is very usefull with classes). 
In your case, PHP expects an instance of the int class, which is not defined. You can use the is_int function to check if the parameter passed is an integer

Comment: Just remove the int from your function call, and at the beginning of your function use an if statement to determine if the parameter passed is an integer. If it is not, you can return an error (or null since that is something you return further in your function)

Comment: I thought you might mean that, so I did it, but now looks like all the variables with the connection strings are not recognizable: host, dbname, username, and password. And the connection was no problem.

Comment: In the code snippet provided these variables are not defined. At first you did not get this error because the function could not be initialised due to the parameter error, meaning the code in the function is not run. Now the parameter error is gone, the errors from within your function do show up.

Comment: I don't think that the case, there's another call stored proc example in the same webpage (no input our output parameters though), and the variables for connections are set exactly the same, and I ran that .php without any problem.

Comment: OK, got it.The dbconfig.php somehow is not working for this script. So I tried to set $dsn,$username, and $password, and define $pdo again, and now it works fine. But yes, I removed typehint. Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: As @user2038893 said, its now possible since php >= 7

Answer (score 0):

You can replace param binding with this:

```
  $stmt->bindParam(':id', $customerNumber);
```

There is no need of the third param in this case.

Comment: That's probably true, but the problem isn't related to this.